# How to generate surface/plane around a real world Object (Like bottle) using Unity & ARCore?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I built an apk using the HelloAR scene (which is provided with ARcore package). The app is only detecting Horizontal surface like table and creates it's own semi-transparent plane over it. When I moved my phone around a bottle, the app again, only created a horizontal plane cutting through the bottle. I expected ARCore to create planes along the bottle as I move my phone around, like polygons in a mesh.

Another scenario is, I placed 2 books on the floor, and each of them have different thickness. But the HelloAR app creates only one semi-transparent horizontal surface over the thicker book, instead of creating two surfaces (one for each book).

What is going wrong here? How can I fix it and make the HelloAR app work more precisely? Please help.

Software: Unity v2018.2,
       ARcore v1.11.0

Comment: At the current state (and probably for the next 3-12 months), ARCore is not capable of this.

Comment: I dont think ARCore is capable of this. You should give a try to hololense

Comment: Your best bet would be to use Vuforia. It supports detection of 3D object using machine learning. If you are interested I can elaborate more.

Comment: @mihoci10, Since ARcore doesn't fit my requirements, I'm looking for alternatives anyway (Vuforia is the major one). It'd really help if you elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

ARCore generates an approximate `point cloud` using a soft movement of the device to identify the featured points, this points are detected by contrast in the different shapes, if you use your application in test mode in unity you can see how the points are placed in your empty scene.

Once the program has enough points at the `"same height"` (I don't know the exact precision), it generates the plane that you can see, but it won't detect planes separated by a difference of 5cm or even more distance.

If you want to know the approximate accuracy of the app, test it with unity and make a script to capture the generated points that have been used to generate the planes, then check the `Y difference` to see which is the tolerance distance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so Vuforia is currently one of the leading SDKs for augmented reality providing a wide area of detection options (Images, Ground, Point, 3D objects, ...)

So regarding your question about detecting a bottle I would most certainly use the 3D model detection feature. You can read the official docs [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ooSQmMrg4g).
You need to first generate an approximate of the object in a 3d modeling software and the use their program to generate the detection model. Then you put this in Unity and setup the detection. (no coding needed)

I have some experience with this kind of detection. I used it to detect a large 2mx2m scale model of an electric vehicle. It works great, you can walk around it and it tracks it through and through. You can see a short official demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ooSQmMrg4g)

Hope it helped to explain this in short!